# Can I send a CloudWatch Metrics namespace to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, metrics, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to send my custom cloudWatch metrics namespace filtered events to an s3 bucket to monitor specific events. I have data coming in from cloudTrail and am filtering the logs I want through metrics in a custom namespace.

I've looked into creating a cloudWatch subscription which will let me filter by specific options like eventName. I'm not sure if this is the only option though.

This is the AWS filtering subscription setup and I've done a similar filtering in cloudWatch by specifying {$.userIdentity.type = Root} with other filters set. So I imagine if I need to go the route of doing a subscription I would do multiple --filter-pattern {$.userIdentity.type = Root} / lines

```
aws logs put-subscription-filter \
    --log-group-name "CloudTrail" \
    --filter-name "RecipientStream" \
    --filter-pattern "{$.userIdentity.type = Root}" \
    --destination-arn "arn:aws:logs:region:999999999999:destination:testDestination"
```

I have a cloudWatch log that is pulling my cloudTrail logs and filtering them through metrics. I would like to sends those results to an s3 bucket I have in place to store the filtered logs from my metrics name space. Is this possible or do I need to use a subscription configuration?

Comment: Have you tried it? What is the result?

Comment: The CloudWatch subscription?